# Is corda connect released?

Tags: corda

Is [corda connect] already released?

Although I could see the documentation of Corda, I could not find the description when I looked at the tutorial.

If it is released, please tell me the location of the document or tutorial.

Comment: where in documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet, it will be soon, later on in the year. R3 will keep you posted with progress.

Comment: Hi Roger,
thank you for your answer.
I am looking forward to the release of Corda Connect in Tokyo.
I would like to use it for the application that I am about to make.